# Запятые, уточнения

Tags: пунктуация

1. *«Этот процесс вполне закономерен, так как новые методологические решения (и просто идеи) возникают, именно при решении задач предельной сложности»*.

Запятую после «возникают,» убрать?

2. *Построение космогонической теории, исходя из принципа понимания информации как всеобщего свойства.*

Нужна ли запятая перед "исходя"?

3. *Каждая подгруппа экспертов имела в качестве основания объединения слов различные описания (инструмент, человек или место), однако, независимо от этого группы были образованы одинаково.*

"Независимо от этого" выделяется запятой?))

4. *В связи с этим необходимо отметить, что лингвистические расчленения высказываний, в которых сказуемые заменяются предикатом (с неизбежной потерей содержательной специфики действия)не всегда оставляют возможность для изучения реальных связей значений (а не только ассоциативных связей).*

Перед "не всегда" стоит запятая?

Comment: user176815, осваивайте уже форматирование понемногу. Судя по всему, вы здесь надолго. ))) И ответы принимать не забывайте. Стрелочки вверх и галочки  при ответах. Стрелочка - за хороший ответ, галочка - за единственный правильный (с вашей точки зрения).

Comment: Спасибо! А я забываю принимать ответы? что надо делать? Нажимаю на стрелочки - ничего не меняется. Или что-то меняется?

Comment: Ответы на свои вопросы вы должны быть способны принимать... Галку видите при ответе? Это "принять ответ". Вот насчет простых лайков - не уверен. Попробую вам репутации добавить, хотя ваши вопросы по большому счету не заслуживают того, ибо утилитарны, но авансом...

Answer (score 1):

1. Убрать, без вариантов. Скоро авторы начнут её внутри слова ставить, вы тоже будете спрашивать, убирать ли? Или просто решили на нас вообще всю работу переложить, даже самую простую? )))
2. Спорно... Фраза корявая, поэтому сомнения. "Исходя" здесь часть составного предлога "исходя их", не деепричастие. И оборот с таким предлогом тоже обычно обособляется. Но не всегда. Если есть тесная связь со скзауемым или вообще является частью составного сказуемого, то точно не обособляется (другие редкие случаи, когда обособлять не надо, опускаю,  не актаульно)    А сказуемого в предложении нет. В результате непонятно, на что ориентироваться. Надо бы уточнить, допускает ли вообще классическая грамматика подобные конструкции. Но пока я бы или запятую убрал (тесная связь с главным членом все-таки), или вообще текст поменял.
   Cмотрите-ка, я был прав. Нашел подтверждение, запятая не нужна.

> [обороты не обособляются] если деепричастие утратило глагольное значение; так, простые отглагольные предлоги благодаря, включая, исключая, кончая, начиная, считая, спустя и составные отглагольные предлоги смотря по, судя по, невзирая на, несмотря на, не доходя до, исходя из, начиная с вместе с относящимися к ним словами не образуют деепричастных оборотов и не обособляются, например: К работе можно приступить начиная с будущей недели (слово начиная можно опустить без ущерба для смысла и структуры предложения); Статистические показатели выводятся исходя из многих данных (слово исходя можно опустить); Будем действовать смотря по обстоятельствам (слово смотря можно опустить).

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm
(Розенталь)

Получается, "Справка" на грамоте погорячилась, считая обособление необходимым "как правило" (кроме случаев оборота, неотделимого от сказуемого).
http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_248

Прервусь пока, вернусь - продолжу

3. Фраза корявая. От чего "этого" независимо"? Но, если менять текст, здесь без запятой никак. Фраза даже читается совсем плохо. 
   Основания для такого обособления можно найти тут (хотя правила не строгие).
   http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum_attach1/
   Будем считать, что тут (как мининимум!) нужно обозначить границы оборота. А почему нет? Наверное, есть и более весомые основания для запятой (таковых много - http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=401 - весь § 75.), но и этого достаточно.

Однако у меня стойкое ощущение, что здесь надо не "независимо от", а как раз "при этом". Вот тогда запятой не надо. Уточните у автора, если можно, насколь ему дорога конструкция "несмотря на" - и почему. "Независимо от" это значит, что какие-то другие группы, независимо от подгрупп, были образованы одинаково...  Абракадабра, короче получается. Лучше всего - контекст. И побольше.

4. Конечно. Вы ж должны закрыть придаточное. Скобки запятую не поглощают. 
   После скобки запятая без пробела, после запятой пробел обязателен. У вас его нет даже после скобки, что тоже неправильно. 
   (+)
   Подумал, может вы сомневаетесь, где придаточное заканчивается... Так не сомневайтесь. Все вместе *"в которых сказуемые заменяются предикатом (с неизбежной потерей содержательной специфики действия)"* является придаточным и обособляется запятыми. Вроде бы, текст лингвистический, вполне себе вам доступный к пониманию.

Comment: Спасибо! очень понравилось второе правило, которое вы прикрепили. Это просто любимый перечень слов автора))), с которым я не знала что делать)).

Comment: Понравилось-то оно понравилось. Но я бы не рекомендовал безоглядно использовать то, что противоречит Розенталю - пусть даже и не в самом большом. Тут вопрос применимости каждого элемента любимого списка, "как правило" не значит обязательно. А так, пользуйтесь, конечно на здоровье, там, на "Грамоте" много таких списков - на все случаи жизни.

Comment: по 3 вопросу хочу уточнить. Независимо от этого, имеется в виду, независимо от того, что были разные описания. Поэтому я поставила запятую. Спасибо вам! Вы просто эксперт!

Comment: Вот это и непонятно. "Независим от того, что каждая подгруппа имела...",  "группы были образованы одинаково". Как это понимать? *Независимо от того, что он был в шляпе, штанов на нем не наблюдалось*. Ну почему "независимо-то"? Очень даже зависимо.  *При том, что он был в шляпе, штанов на нем не наблюдалось* - вот это понятно. Или у меня какая-то смысловая слепота возникла, которую вы пока не вылечили.